# JsReport Chrome-pdf recipe landscape option

Tags: pdf, chromium, recipe, jsreport

I want to set landscape mode for jsreport in chromium (chrome-pdf), or generally set any options from page https://jsreport.net/learn/chrome-pdf

Answer (score 0):

It could be set this way:

```
HttpContext.JsReportFeature().Recipe(Recipe.ChromePdf)
         .Configure((r) =>
          {
              r.Template.Chrome = new Chrome {Landscape = true};
          });
```